# Where to put my business login in vaadin application

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have a small vaadin application which would allow users to input some data in a form (employee details like name, surname, address etc) and store each employee object in a List.
This is the structure so far:

```
EmployeeForm
    src/main/java
        com.vaadin.project.EmployeeForm
            MyUI.java
        employee
            Address.java
            Employee.java
```

So, for testing purposes I created an Employee object directly inside MyUI.java, like so:

```
Address address1 = new Address(34, "Flinch Street","KT25AG");
Employee employee1 = new Employee("John","Smith", "Male", 39, address1, "Permanent", 8765);
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employee.add(employee1);
for(Employee currentEmployee : employee ){
    System.out.println(employee);
}
```

just to make sure things works, but it seems wrong to do that there, so I'd like to create another class that deals with all the business logic, and I was wondering what the best way would be.
By business login I mean that What I need to make sure it happens is that after users fill in the form on the MyUI.java file and click the submit button a new Employee object is created and stored in a List.
So I'm thinking, can I have a function call in MyUI.java, something like `createNewEmployee()` and then have that function defined inside another class `CreateEmployee.java`, get all the data I need (name, surname, address etc) from  MyUI.java and construct the new Employee object in `CreateEmployee.java`? Does that sound reasonable? It's easy enough to do that inside the MyUI.java but I reckon that should only deal with the GUI, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a service design pattern where all business logic is encapsulated in services.

You would have an EmployeeService class that in the simplest form could be instantiated as a member variable on your MyUI.  My services are usually stateless and have business methods.  In your example it would have the method called createNewEmployee().

I typically like to have an interface for my services.  Some people use an additional layer for any data source interaction (search for DAOs).  I like to keep it simple and access the data sources directly from my service.

If I think I'm going to have a multiple implementations or have need to swap out data sources in the future then I would have an AbstractEmployeeService where most of the true business logic would go and then have a data source specific implementation of that to do data source interaction (for example a JdbcEmployeeService.)

If you want to get more advanced, I'd recommend using Spring to inject your services.  See http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/ to get a start.

Different developers will have different opinions.  There is no one right answer, but you are on the right path to separate our your business logic!

Comment: thanks for the advice, I created a EmployeeService class and implemented  `createNewEmployee(...)` and `clearTextFields(...)` there (both called from MyUI.java ) and it all works. Now there is another related thing, what do I do  with error handling, meaning, should I create another separate class for it or deal with it inside MyUI.java?

Comment: I like using `setErrorHandler` on the UI and popping my own custom error window to handle errors across the board.  If I need special error handling, then I can handle it where needed.  I'll like the bubble errors up by wrapping in RuntimeExceptions whenever I'm not sure how to handle an error.  I usually log the exception in the error handler as well.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of that at hand? [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-errors.html) seems to handle them in the UI. In my specific case I need to handle empty input fields and at least a NumberFormatException in case the string in the textField can't be converted into an int